# Is there a framework to generate config files and validation scripts

Tags: python, configuration, installation

I need deploy a complex system to customers. There are many config files which contain around two hundreds parameters which customers should modify. Manually modifying the config files is tricky and easy to make mistakes. So I want to provide a user-friendly way.

- I prepare all config files which contain placeholders, e.g. config file template;
- The key of all placeholders is placed in one file in which user fillin the required information, I name it as information file; Later, I may provide a HTML and js to generate the information file so that customers just fill information in HTML form.

  Either information file or HTML need comments to tell customers what they should fill;

  The information file got from customers should be validated, at least syntax validation;
- Finally, I can generate the target config files with the above two input;

What I need to prepare are config file template, information file and validation scripts. The work is somehow boring. I want to use metadata to generate the information file and validation scripts.

Is there any framework to do such work or any more wise methods?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [ConfigObj](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/) package ([homepage](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml)).  This has at least some of what you are looking for, an easy way to setup defaults and validate the values.  Simple validation looks very easy to setup, and you can write custom validation methods if you need something more complex.

It should be relatively easy to write a HTML front end that creates a config file, then the generated config file can be passed through ConfigObj.